# Validate XML against Schema that imports another xsd in WSO2 ESB

Tags: xml, wso2, xsd-validation, wso2-esb

I am trying to validate my incoming XML request against the schema. Basically there are three different schemas CDM_GeneralLedger_v1.0.xsd, GLBookingTypes-v1.0.xsd, CDM_ISOCurrencyCodes_v1.0.xsd (CDM_GeneralLedger_v1.0.xsd imports CDM_ISOCurrencyCodes_v1.0.xsd and GLBookingTypes-v1.0.xsd imports CDM_GeneralLedger_v1.0.xsd) . now in WSO2 ESB I am using validate mediator but it is giving me an exception given below.

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-26 09:58:36,989]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager} -  Task manager for service : GLBookingService shutdown {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-26 09:58:36,990]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager} -  Task manager for service : GLBookingService [re-]initialized {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-26 09:58:37,991]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager} -  Reconnection attempt: 1 for service: GLBookingService was successful! {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-26 09:59:13,409]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: ...CDMRequestReceived...WSAction: urn:mediate...CDMRequestReceived...SOAPAction: urn:mediate...CDMRequestReceived...MessageID: ID:WIN-RPVU8RVH42Q-49271-1416974777862-3:1:1:1:16...CDMRequestReceived...Direction: request {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-26 09:59:13,422]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.util.jaxp.SchemaResourceResolver} -  Unable to resolve schema resource : "CDM_GeneralLedger_v1.0.xsd". External schema resources not defined in Validate mediator configuration {org.apache.synapse.util.jaxp.SchemaResourceResolver}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-26 09:59:13,441] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.ValidateMediator} -  Error creating a new schema objects for schemas : [Value {name ='null', keyValue ='conf:/XSD/GLBookingTypes-v1.0.xsd'}, Value {name ='null', keyValue ='conf:/CDM_GeneralLedger_custom_v1.0.xsd'}] {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.ValidateMediator}
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 59; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'cdm:GLBookingType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseLocal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseLocalElements(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.ValidateMediator.mediate(ValidateMediator.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:196)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:166)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.handleIncomingMessage(AbstractTransportListener.java:328)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSMessageReceiver.processThoughEngine(JMSMessageReceiver.java:200)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSMessageReceiver.onMessage(JMSMessageReceiver.java:122)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.handleMessage(ServiceTaskManager.java:556)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.run(ServiceTaskManager.java:449)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I can't post my XSDs due to confidentiality. But same xsds working fine in other tool like TIBCO, Talend.

The Validate mediator source code is:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="validateXml">
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="CMMHeader" expression="$body/Message/CMMHeader" scope="default" type="OM"></property>
   <validate xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:tns="http://com.glbooking/v1/data" source="//tns:GLBookingMessage">
      <schema key="conf:/XSD/CDM_GeneralLedger_v1.0.xsd"></schema>
      <schema key="conf:/XSD/GLBookingTypes-v1.0.xsd"></schema>
      <schema key="conf:/XSD/CDM_ISOCurrencyCodes_v1.0.xsd"></schema>
      <on-fail>
         <makefault version="pox">
            <reason value="XML Request is invalid. Error while validating "></reason>
            <detail>Invalid XML Request</detail>
         </makefault>
         <log level="full" category="ERROR"></log>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <Error>
                  <Header>$2</Header>
                  <ErrorCode>101504</ErrorCode>
                  <ErrorMessage>Error while validating XML</ErrorMessage>
                  <ErrorException>$1</ErrorException>
               </Error>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" evaluator="xml"></arg>
               <arg expression="$ctx:CMMHeader" evaluator="xml"></arg>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send>
            <endpoint key="conf:/GLBookingErrorQueue_EPLOCAL"></endpoint>
         </send>
         <drop></drop>
      </on-fail>
   </validate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External schema files that are out side of your main schema should defined 
using resource element

```
<validate>
    <schema key="conf:/XSD/Employee.xsd"/>
    <resource location="XSD/Address.xsd" key="conf:XSD/Address.xsd"/>
    <on-fail>
        <makefault version="soap11">
            <code xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" value="soap11Env:Client"/>
            <reason value="Invalid xml"/>
            <role/>
        </makefault>
    </on-fail>
</validate>
```

The value for location attribute (XSD/Address.xsd in above example) should be value of schemaLocation attribute

Here is sample schema files

Employee.xsd

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.srd.com/Employee" xmlns="http://schemas.srd.com/Employee" xmlns:addr="http://schemas.srd.com/Address"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.srd.com/Address" schemaLocation="XSD/Address.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="Employee">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ename" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="deptno" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="hiredate" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="job" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="mgr" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sal" type="xs:decimal"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="comm" type="xs:decimal"/>
                <xs:element ref="addr:Address"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Address.xsd

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.srd.com/Address" xmlns="http://schemas.srd.com/Address" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Address">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="city" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="state" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="country" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="postalCode" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I have already solved the issue by using same approach.